# Is this porphyra (nori) seaweed mislabeled?

Tags: seafood

I bought a pack of dried seaweed and it's labeled as 'porphyra', after googling a little this is apparently the type of seaweed used as nori, i.e. the type you wrap sushi with. It looks nothing like the thin sheets of nori I'm used to however. It actually kinda looks like kombu to me. Is it possible that it was mislabeled?

[image]

Here is the packaging. [image]

Comment: Porphyra is a genus with around 80 subspecies, so I'd expect a lot of variation. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porphyra

Comment: Can you get a picture of any Chinese or kanji on the package?

Comment: Im afraid there was no chinese on the packaging